# Terraform using static access id and secret creates instance but not in the account of those credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform

I'm trying to create an AWS EC2 instance using Terraform. It says it creates the instance and if I try run apply again it says it's already there. It isn't being created in my AWS account though and I can't figure out what's going on. I've regenerated the access id and secret from my AWS account and placed those directly in the .tf file and according to Terraform successfully created the instance - it's just not appearing in AWS.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure it is being created in the AWS region you are looking at?

Comment: Can you answer formally so I can accept yours as the answer please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common reason for not being able to find resources in the AWS UI is due to looking at the wrong AWS region. Make note of the region in the top-right corner of the AWS console, and the region you are configuring Terraform to use.